# Radius doesn't decrease

Tags: jquery, canvas

Here's my script: http://jsfiddle.net/VDC5h/

```
var xStart;
var yStart;
var xStop;
var yStop;
var i=0;
var d=0;
$('#obrazek').click( function(e) {
    if(i==1)
    {
        i=2;
    }
    if(i==0)
    {
        var posX = $(this).offset().left, posY = $(this).offset().top;
        xStart=(e.pageX - posX);
        yStart=(e.pageY - posY);
        i=1;
    }
});
$("#obrazek").on( "mousemove", function(e) {  
    if(i==1)
    {
        var posX = $(this).offset().left, posY = $(this).offset().top;
        xStop=(e.pageX - posX);
        yStop=(e.pageY - posY); 
        d=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xStart-xStop,2)+Math.pow(yStart-yStop,2))
        $('canvas').drawArc({
            fillStyle: '#000',
            x: xStart, 
            y: yStart,
            radius: d
        });
        $('#d').html(d);                                
    }
});
```

It works, but I can't reduce the radius. The radius only increases. On the bottom is "d". "d"=radius. When "d" decreases, radius doesn't decrease.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: It is decreasing, but you are drawing over the top of the canvas. You need to erase the previous drawing first.

Comment: Right. Thanks. I added cleaning functions and operates.

Comment: +1 for providing a JSFiddle. I added a quick working example for you (and updated JSFiddle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clear the previous drawing first:

e.g.

### http://jsfiddle.net/VDC5h/1/

```
    // Erase previous drawing
    $('canvas').drawArc({
        fillStyle: '#fff',
        x: xStart, 
        y: yStart,
        radius: d+1});
    d=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xStart-xStop,2)+Math.pow(yStart-yStop,2))
    $('canvas').drawArc({
        fillStyle: '#000',
        x: xStart, 
        y: yStart,
        radius: d
    });
```

Note: I cheated and simply redrew the previous arc (in white) using the old size, but you should probably just clear the canvas instead. I added 1 to d as rounding errors leave a faint trail.

Comment: Yes. Now I know... Thx :)